# Getting dock area where an MFC CDockablePane was docked

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, dock

I am working on a project that totally does not want to use the built-in `window/dock` state and position saving of `MFC`. This means that in my main frame, I set `EnableLoadDockState(FALSE)`. As much as I love to change it back to TRUE, I can't.

I plan on getting the position where a `CDockablePane` was docked through `onAfterDock()` of my `CDockablePane`. My problem is I have no idea on how to get whether it was placed on the side, top or bottom, on another `CDockablePane`.

Is there a way to get this information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a way to get it, but it's not going to be easy or pretty.

A you're trapping the `OnAfterDock`, I guess you're not interested in floating panes. So, for docked panes, you can use `CDockablePane::GetDefaultPaneDivider` ([MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb983496.aspx)), which returns - as MSDN says:

> A valid `CPaneDivider` object if the dockable pane is docked to the main frame window, or NULL if the dockable pane is not docked or if it is floating.

The `CPaneDivider` object ([MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb983707.aspx))

> ...divides two panes, divides two groups of panes, or separates a group of panes from the client area of the main frame window

The following partial screenshot says more:

[image: cpanedivider]

So, for a regular pane divider, you can use the methods available on `CPaneDivider` to find the other pane, or another embedded `CPaneDivider` (so recursive interrogation necessary here) and check if the divider is horizontal or vertical etc.

For the other case described above, look at the `CPaneContainerManager` class, which (again [as MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb982952.aspx))

> ...manages the storage and display of the current docking layout

From here, you can again drill down through the whole docking hierarchy that starts from your original docked pane.

If I were you, I would really really look again at using `EnableLoadDockState` or at least browse the MFC source code to see if there are any internal helper classes/functions that you can reuse.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it. I really hate it that EnableLoadDockState was set to false, I can't even make my tabbed docks untab correctly when more than 2 are docked. I will update this once I make any real progress.

Comment: After trying to make it work, I more or less gave up. I was able to get dock size and window size and position by modifying the savestate of the derived cDockablePane class but docking position was too difficult and complicated to save since these are stored in CDockingManager and the attributes needed are protected.

Answer (score 4):

I've just solved this issue. I can check `CDockablePane`'s `dwStyle` (`GetPaneStyle()`) for `CBRS_ALIGN_LEFT`, `CBRS_ALIGN_RIGHT`, etc. No complex methods. Simple.

Comment: So does the style change dynamically when it's docked? Also, this doesn't help to find the object it was docked to, which AIUI was part of the OP's problem.

Comment: @RogerRowland Yes, the style changes dynamically. And you are right. Finally, I have switched to `EnableLoadDockState(TRUE)`. I have found `protected` code within docking  manager object and made a hack to call it. But some minutes later I gave up. Sorry. Maybe you can copy that code to your own docking manager hacking class.